# Drupal Feeds Exporter

Tags: feeds

Hi i am using drupal [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module to export csv data into my website, but when csv has more than 700 lines the exporter is failing saying "***Source file is not in UFT-8 encoding***",but if i upload same file with less that 700 line export is working fine.

Comment: Check if a record after 700th line is causing this. Just manually inspect the file using LibreOffice Calc or Excel.